# What is the impact of unbalanced longitudinal data?

Tags: mixed-model, longitudinal-data-analysis

I'm quite new to the concept of correlated data still, and I was have a few questions about unbalanced longitudinal data.

**Let's say we are using a linear mixed model:**

**1)** what is the impact of not adjusting the unbalanced nature of time?

**2)** what would we be assuming if we **did not** adjust?

**3)** what would be the assumptions if we **did** adjust for the unbalanced nature?

**3)** is it critical to adjust for unbalanced time?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT** for my situation Y is a repeated measure, but the time at which it's measured is unbalanced for the participants

Comment: Linear Mixed Model: $Y=X\beta+Z\gamma+\epsilon, \gamma \sim N(0,G), \epsilon \sim N (0,R)$. What part(s) is your (un)balanced nature involved?

Comment: @user158565 for my situation Y is a repeated measure, but the time at which it's measured is unbalanced for the participants

Answer (score 1):

Linear mixed models can work with unbalanced data, i.e., there is no problem if subjects are measured at completely different time points. You do not need to group time points together to create discrete follow-up times. In the specification of the model you may need to account for potentially nonlinear profiles over time, using splines or polynomials.